# Javascript Function Requires a name error

Tags: javascript, function

In this line of code:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(ajax.readyState == 4) {
        function() {document.getElementById(f3).innerHTML = ajax.responseText};
    }
};
```

This line:

```
...
        function() {document.getElementById(f3).innerHTML = ajax.responseText};
...
```

is getting an error that the Function must be named.

This is the full scope of the code:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(ajax.readyState == 4) {
        function() {document.getElementById(f3).innerHTML = ajax.responseText};
    }
};
var urlToOpen = "~.$_tFileName.qq~?pg=admin_main&load=subscriptionAdmin&view=setANewVar&n=" + f1 + "&v=" + f2 + "~.$SessId.q~" + "&stopIEcache=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*99999);
ajax.open("GET", urlToOpen, true);
ajax.send(null);
```

The Tilde Marks (~) are because this file is built with Perl syntax. the output is a full url... for example:

https://www.google.com/search?pg=admin_main&load=subscriptionAdmin&view=setANewVar&n=
of course it is not on Google... just put that url instead of the real one.

Can you tell me what is wrong with that line? and how I can make it work?

Thank you.
Rich

Answer (score 2):

Remove `function()` it's unnecessary to have it there

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(ajax.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById(f3).innerHTML = ajax.responseText
    }
};
var urlToOpen = "~.$_tFileName.qq~?pg=admin_main&load=subscriptionAdmin&view=setANewVar&n=" + f1 + "&v=" + f2 + "~.$SessId.q~" + "&stopIEcache=" + Date.now();
ajax.open("GET", urlToOpen, true);
ajax.send(null); // PS. you can also remove null -> ajax.send();
```